# Implementing a seedable CSPRNG

Tags: vb.net, random, cryptography, random-seed

I have looked for, and cannot find, any decent means of implementing a **seedable** Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) for VB.Net. Anybody with cryptography/programming/VB experience knows `Rnd()` is crypto-suicide. Also, it looks like `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` does not (practically) allow seeding (From SO: **[no cryptography random generator seed allowed in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318078/no-cryptography-random-generator-seed-allowed-in-c)**).

So, realistically, if I'm building a VB.Net Windows Forms application (Visual Studio 2015), how on earth do I implement a **seedable** CSPRNG where a password hash could be used as the seed? Is there a common library or something that people use? Or is it truly just kinda "fend-for-yourself?"

Comment: If you want a cryptographically suitable random number, why would you also want to seed?  Maybe more about what you are really after would help.

Comment: Well, for example, I **can** seed the `Rnd` function.  But as I understand it, that function is known to produce terrible results even when seeded, such that different seeds might STILL result in a collision.

Comment: It is still not clear *what* you are trying to do (especially considering `a password hash could be used as the seed`).  An RNG from a seed is generally antithetical to CSPRNG.

Comment: Basically, I want to generate random bytes (stored in an array) that will be used to XOR the byte-data in a target file.  Since having a "key file" is cumbersome, I want to use a PRNG to repeat the byte-sequence once supplied with the correct password (the one used to encrypt the data). I assumed I needed a "CS" PRNG since things like `Rnd()` don't even work well when supplied with a quality seed (like a good password).

Comment: `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(Byte())` will give you an array of CSPRNG values.  Have you considered a cryptostream for the file rather than XOR-ing the file?  Hardly seems worth the bother if the aim is to protect the file.

Comment: Being pretty new to VS2015 and VB.Net, I had not (didn't know it existed).  I will look more into that, then.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want, update the question to something solution based

Comment: @DjM This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187) to me. You probably want a stream cipher (which does the XORing). You can derive the key for the cipher from a password with PBKDF2 (with many iterations and a random salt) or similar. Note that block ciphers such as AES can be transformed into stream ciphers by using modes like CTR or CFB.